# time() outputs wrong when called inside wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, time, timezone, localtime

php's time() strangely outputs wrong when called inside WordPress.

I'm pretty sure my server time is setup correctly both Linux & php.
The correct timezone for me is UTC+2. For example let's say the time is 10:50
linux time: 10:50
php time(): 10:50
inside wp time(): 8:50

My timezone setting in wp is also correctly set to Europe. I wonder why this is happening any ideas ?

Here's a screenshot (dont mind the minutes screenshots taken in between): http://s29.postimg.org/4s80u06nb/wptimmm.jpg

PS: I avoid this confusion by using `$now = current_time( 'timestamp', 0 );` but I don't want to run an extra function for such a simple thing every time.

Comment: Well.. If your severs clock is correct and WP is wrong, I'd say its a WP issue.

Comment: Yeah but I wonder what that might be. Because interestingly, my WP plugins display the time correctly - UTC+2. However when I call time() inside my theme's functions.php I get UTC.

Comment: JavaScript will show times in the clients timezone - perhaps this is the missing link.

Comment: did you ever fine a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Before outputting the time() add a [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/date_default_timezone_set) declaration before hand. This will firstly confirm if you have the correct timezone set and secondly will let you you know that time() *IS* using your your previous timezone declaration.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It might work but I'd hate to add that every time. I'd rather find an actual overall solution to the problem.

Comment: My suggestion will help you debug. Either a) time() is not seeing your first timezone set or b) your timezone set is not configured properly(wrong, commented out etc).

Comment: It seems it's the default behaviour for WP to set the timezone to UTC regardless of your choice. I guess I have no other option other than getting the timestamp with current_time( 'timestamp', 0 );

Comment: Then add the correct timezone declaration to the bootstrap/index file. As the last timezone declaration visible it should be applied. Edit: If wp-settings.php is not applying then something is seriously amiss. But add it to the index and see if time() picks it up correctly.

Comment: wp-settings modification would probably work, but apprarently it might cause some other issues- http://weston.ruter.net/2013/04/02/do-not-change-the-default-timezone-from-utc-in-wordpress/

Comment: You would think that changing a timezone would be easy :) In that case stick a declaration within index.php, it should affect time() within your pages without affecting anything that uses wp-settings

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks ok. You are trying to compare time from 2 different time zones.

**EET= UTC +2h in your case.**

So if you want to have the same time in few place, you need to use common time zone for all of them.

Comment: Not really. I expect time() to output 10:50 inside WP as well. Instead it outputs 8:50. I wonder what causes WP to output UTC for time() when my time is set to UTC+2 everywhere

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress sets date_default_timezone_set to UTC. Change that settings from within wordpress (wp-settings.php).

Comment: Thanks, but that seems to be problematic either: http://weston.ruter.net/2013/04/02/do-not-change-the-default-timezone-from-utc-in-wordpress/